# How do I use php to put an array index inside html tags

Tags: php, html, arrays, tags

I am interning for the summer and am crash coursing in php. My boss wants me to insert key words inside the img alt tagss using php. Since its an include file he just wants it to be done once instead of hard coding each page. I wrote an array with each landing page in it, but he added some stuff and wants me to finish it. I'm not sure how to bring it all together:

```
<?php

$pages = array("index.php" => "Home Page", "locations.php"=>"Locations","faq.php" => "Frequently Asked Questions",   "contact.php" => "Contact Us", "aboutus.php" => "About Us",);

$real_url_link = $_SERVER['URI'];

parse_url($real_url_link);

echo $pages[$url];

?>
```

this is the slide show with the empty alt tags:

```
                <div align="center" id="pics">
                    <img src="../animation-pics/slide1.jpg" alt="" width="1000" height="341" border="0">
                    <img src="../animation-pics/slide2.jpg" alt="" width="1000" height="341" border="0">
                    <img src="../animation-pics/slide3.jpg" alt="" width="1000" height="341" border="0">
                    <img src="../animation-pics/slide4.jpg" alt="" width="1000" height="341" border="0">
                    <img src="../animation-pics/slide5.jpg" alt="" width="1000" height="341" border="0">
                </div>  

            </tr>
```

'

I know some of this stuff isn't really doing anything but he said it should only take a few lines work

an example of it working would be:
for index. php

```
            <tr>

                <div align="center" id="pics">
                    <img src="../animation-pics/slide1.jpg" alt="Home Page" width="1000" height="341" border="0">
                    <img src="../animation-pics/slide2.jpg" alt="Home Page" width="1000" height="341" border="0">
                    <img src="../animation-pics/slide3.jpg" alt="Home Page" width="1000" height="341" border="0">
                    <img src="../animation-pics/slide4.jpg" alt="Home Page" width="1000" height="341" border="0">
                    <img src="../animation-pics/slide5.jpg" alt="Home Page" width="1000" height="341" border="0">
                </div>  

            </tr>
```

'

Comment: Fix the syntax error first

Comment: you want to add index.php, locations.php, etc. in alt tags ?

Comment: I want to add the key words that go with each page such as "Home Page" for index.php

Comment: @user3824140 Why did you talk about slide show so? Give an HTML section of what you expect as result.

Comment: for index.php the alt tags would look like this :<img src="../animation-pics/slide1.jpg" alt="Home Page" width="1000" height="341" border="0"> instead of being empty

Comment: so, when on index.php page, all slides alt tags should have Home Page ?

Comment: Yes, and for the other pages they would contain their corresponding key words

Comment: @user3824140 may be this is your purpose: <img src="../animation-pics/slide1.jpg" alt="<?=array_keys($pages,$pages[$url])?>" width="1000" height="341" border="0">

Comment: what value you are getting in $_SERVER['URI'] ?

Comment: I don't think its doing anything, when I comment it out the page stays the same

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right

```
<div align="center" id="pics">
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    <?php foreach($pages as $link => $desc): ?>
        <img src="../animation-pics/slide<?php echo $i++; ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $desc; ?>" width="1000" height="341" border="0">
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: When another link is clicked the tags would change to match the page, there would be five since there are five images in the slideshow, I might have explained it badly